# C# custom json serialization converter to set all default value of an object to null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.text.json

I have a nested object that looks like:

```
public record Options
{
    public BatterySettings BatterySettings { get; init; } = new();
    public LogSettings LogSettings { get; init; } = new();
}

public record LogSettings 
{
    public string SourceName { get; init; } = "Default";
}

public record BatterySettings
{
    public int BatteryLevel { get; init; } = 5;
    public string BatteryHealth { get; init; } = "Normal";
    public BatteryLocations BatteryLocation { get; init; } = BatteryLocations.North;
}

public enum BatteryLocations
{
    North,
    South
}
```

After initializing the object and setting some properties i.e.:

```
var opt = new Options 
{
    BatterySettings = new BatterySettings {
        BatteryLevel = 10,
        BatteryHealth = "Low"
    }   
}
```

I would like to get a JSON string that represents this object `opt` **while having all the default value set to null** i.e. in this above example, the resulting `opt` JSON string would look like:

```json
{
   "BatterySettings":{
      "BatteryLevel":10,
      "BatteryHealth":"Low",
      "BatteryLocation":null
   },
   "LogSettings":{
      "SourceName":null
   }
}
```

Is there a built-in way in .NET to do such a thing?

**Edit 1**: the built-in way of utilizing the null serialization settings would not work since the object `Options` has non-null default values for its properties and sub-object properties.
It seems that a custom converter would need to be implemented here though I have trouble figuring out the correct approach to this due to having to compare default values with the object's current value for every given nodes

Comment: BatteryLocation is an enum, so having null is not a valid value for this property. You can make this nullable and assign default value as null

Comment: Just remove "Default" and "Normal from your class.Default value for a string is null. Also it is not the best idea to use new() in your root class. It is just an extra work that is not needed.

Comment: @Jasmeet I would like to have the resulting json string to have the property BatteryLocation: null if the object's current value is == to the default object value (in this case BatteryLocations.North)

Comment: @Serge I can't remove the default values since they are part of the design constraints, hence the challenging aspect of this question unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post I will show you how can you serialize the `BatterySettings`

- if the property value is the same as the auto-generated property's default value then serialize it as `null`
- if the property value is different than the auto-generated property's default value then serialize it as it is

In your particular case the default values of your auto-generated properties may or may not be the same as the [run-time defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values). So, we can't use the `default` operator. To solve this problem I suggest the following "trick"

```
public record BatterySettings
{
    private const int BatteryLevelDefault = 5;
    public int BatteryLevel { get; init; } = BatteryLevelDefault;

    private const string BatteryHealthDefault = "Normal";
    public string BatteryHealth { get; init; } = BatteryHealthDefault;

    private const BatteryLocations BatteryLocationDefault = BatteryLocations.North;
    public BatteryLocations BatteryLocation { get; init; } = BatteryLocationDefault;
}
```

So, the "trick" is that we have a dedicated constant field for each property to store the default values. I've marked them as `private` so other class can't access them only via reflection.

---

Now let's see how the converter looks like for this data structure.
*(Please note that this is not production-ready code. It is just for demonstration purposes.)*

```
class BatterySettingsConverter : JsonConverter<BatterySettings>
{
    private readonly PropertyInfo[] Properties = typeof(BatterySettings).GetProperties();
    private readonly FieldInfo[] ConstFields = typeof(BatterySettings).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    public override BatterySettings? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, BatterySettings? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, BatterySettings? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = new JObject();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Properties)
        {
            var defaultValueField = ConstFields.FirstOrDefault(fi => fi.Name.StartsWith(prop.Name));
            if (!prop.CanRead || defaultValueField == null)
                continue;
            
            object propVal = prop.GetValue(value);
            object defaultVal = defaultValueField.GetValue(value);
            JToken serializeVal = !propVal.Equals(defaultVal) ? JToken.FromObject(propVal, serializer) : null;

            result.Add(prop.Name, serializeVal);           
        }
        result.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

- I've stored on the class-level the properties and the fields of the `BatterySettings` record
- Inside the `WriteJson`, first I create an accumulator object (`result`)
- Then I iterate through the properties and try to find the matching field

  - If the related field is not exist / the property does not have a getter then I simply skip it
  - *This logic could be and should be tailored to your needs*
- I retrieve the property's actual value and the constant field's value
- Based on the result of equality check I decide what to serialize
- At the very end I ask json.net to perform the serialization of the accumulator object

---

After I have decorated the `BatterySettings` with the following attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof(BatterySettingsConverter))]` then I can perform some testing

```
var x = new BatterySettings();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x); 
//{"BatteryLevel":null,"BatteryHealth":null,"BatteryLocation":null}

var y = new BatterySettings() { BatteryHealth = "A"}; 
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y); 
//{"BatteryLevel":null,"BatteryHealth":"A","BatteryLocation":null}

var z = new BatterySettings() { BatteryLocation = BatteryLocation.South};
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(z); 
//{"BatteryLevel":null,"BatteryHealth":null,"BatteryLocation":1}
```

---

You can apply the same logic for the rest of your domain classes/records/sturcts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it! This solution certainly works in the case of a single class, however this would mean that for objects containing sub-classes a new custom JsonConverter would have to be implemented for every object? Is it possible to perform a loop in the WriteJson method that goes through all the objects properties recursively in a Breadth First Search manner to perform the conditional check to set the prop value to null? Basically I am trying to see how I can write just 1 custom converter for the top-most class only (in this case the record Options)

Comment: @K.Vu I've shared with you the basic idea how to perform your conditional serialization logic. I think this can be easily generalized in the way that the converter can serialize any data structure in the same way. Hints: 1) Use `JsonConverter` rather than `JsonConverter<T>` 2) Do not use class-level members to store property and field infos.

Comment: I see! Could you elaborate a bit more on your point `2) Do not use class-level members to store property and field infos`, I'm not sure I totally understand it since in your proposed solution all the default values are private and contained at the class level for each object

Comment: @K.Vu In my example I had two class-level readonly members (`Properties` and `ConstFields`) . If you want to create a converter which can work against multiple types then these information should be retrieved inside the `WriteJson` through `value.GetType()`. In the [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) the `WriteJson`'s `value` parameter's type is `object`, not a strongly typed parameter. Is it clear know or shall I further elaborate on some part?

Comment: Thank you for the precision! The solution worked beautifully by using Newtonsoft (Json.net)'s JsonConverter without a type, however I am trying to implement this custom converter using the `System.Text.Json JsonConverter` and the latter seem to require a specific type to be passed i.e. `JsonConverter<T>`. Do you know if it is possible to implement a non-typed JsonConverter using `System.Text.Json.JsonConverter`?

Comment: @K.Vu Well, the [non-generic `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter?view=net-7.0) is just an `abstract` class which does not expose anything useful from serialization perspective. You can create a `JsonConverter<object>` to mimic the Json.NET's `JsonConverter`. For more details, please check out this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0).

Answer (score 1):

In case of Json.Net there is a `NullValueHandling` settings under the `JsonSerializerSettings` where you can control the [null values' serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm).

```
var settings new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(opt, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

In case of System.Text.Json there is a `WhenWritingNull` settings (*please be aware that `IgnoreNullValues` is obsolete*) under the `JsonSerializerOptions` where you can control the [null values' serialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignorecondition?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-serialization-jsonignorecondition-whenwritingnull).

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never
};

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Options>(opt,options);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however the issue with using those null value serialization is that they wouldn't work in my example since the object 'Options' has non-null default values so when serializing the object, all the default value fields would be populated with the default values in the json, which I do not want. Id like those fields to be null instead

Comment: @K.Vu If you want to serialize a non-nullable field as null if it has a default value then you need to write a custom converter. There is no built-in support for that because this use case is quite rare IMHO.

Comment: I see, I figured some sort of custom solution would need to be done. Do you have any pointers as to how to approach a case like this though? I could serialize the object 'opt' as a JToken/JContainer and loop through its children, but I have trouble visualizing how I can loop through the default values of the Options object to perform a comparison to set the former's properties to null if it is a default value.

Comment: @K.Vu I've posted another solution proposal, please check it!